# Stability of carbocations: CF3+ vs CH3+

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, carbocation

Is $\ce{CF_3+}$ more stable than $\ce{CH_3+}$?

In $\ce{CF_3+}$, there is $\ce{C-F}$ back bonding that increases  stability of the carbocations. But -I effect of $\ce{F}$ dominates +R effect and this decreases the carbocation stability. How can I compare these two competing effects to find the more stable carbocation?

Also, is $\ce{CF_3+}$ more stable than $\ce{CH3-CH+-CH_3}$ and tert-butyl carbocation?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Is CF3+ more stable that CH3+

Comment: Yeah, but your first sentence answers that question... You said that the -I effect outweighs the +R effect and therefore the $\ce{CF3+}$ cation is less stable. So your question is probably *how* to judge which of the inductive or resonance effect is larger. I mean, I think this could be a good question about competing effects if you are clear about what you are asking.

Comment: @orthocresol: Is CF3+ more stable than propyl carbocation (+ charge at secod carbon of propane) and tert-butyl carbocation?

Comment: Alright, I don't know the answer to that. You'll have to edit it into the post and hopefully someone else will answer.

Comment: Is there evidence that CF3(+) is more stable than CH3(+)? My intuition would be that methyl cation is more stable.

Comment: @jerepierre : at DMSO, pka of methane is about 56 while pka of CF3H is 25-30

Comment: But deprotonation forms the *anion*, not the cation. The $\ce{CF3-}$ anion is trigonal pyramidal, so there's no backdonation from fluorine, and it's stabilised by the -I effect of fluorine, which is what leads to the smaller $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$.

Comment: So the pka values only explain the carbanion stability....

Comment: In the gas phase, the trifluoromethyl carbocation is more stable than the methyl carbocation, See p. 170 [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=BH2vPZBIUXcC&pg=PA170&lpg=PA170&dq=trifluoromethyl+cation+stability&source=bl&ots=PJgPFh4BOl&sig=MwERiXWc1pz_zxdfRx-xEKo5OUE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFcQ6AEwCWoVChMIoZTI29j0yAIVA9JjCh3_6Qot#v=onepage&q=trifluoromethyl%20cation%20stability&f=false)

Comment: and p.54 [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=u7VbDUD3WMQC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=trifluoromethyl+cation+stability&source=bl&ots=RP2jo_DpZs&sig=jiRxXvcD5qmXP6IqjG0l-D2JqKw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAWoVChMIoZTI29j0yAIVA9JjCh3_6Qot#v=onepage&q=trifluoromethyl%20cation%20stability&f=false)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$\ce{CF3+}$ is more stable than $\ce{CH3+}$. The comparison between -I and +R effect is made while talking about activation or deactivation of halogens when substituted on benzene. Fluorine always stabilises a carbocation to a large extent because of a very good overlap of $\ce{2p -~2p}$ orbitals.

Comment: So should I consider that net  electron donating tendency of halogens to carbocations is more than the net electron withdrawing tendency?

Comment: @user1825567: I guess the extent of effect follows, _Mesomeric > Resonance > Inductive_. No?

Comment: @Rahul Verma  Sorry, I am no longer fluent in this topic. BTW...All the best for JEE !

Comment: @RahulVerma: Aren't 'mesomeric' and 'resonance' effects the same thing? According to the [Gold Book](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/M03844) 'mesomeric effect' is an alternate term for 'resonance effect'. If so, can you tell what did you mean by 'Mesomeric > Resonance'?

Comment: @GuruVishnu It seems like a mistake, mesomeric effect and resonance are essentially the same thing, and this effect is stronger than inductive

Comment: @GuruVishnu, the mesomeric effect is included / subsumed in resonance effect category. It is a special case of resonance, where $\ce{\pi}$ orbitals are in conjugation. Other cases of resonance can include $\ce{C^+}$ or $\ce{C^-}$

Comment: @RahulVerma  Is there any explanation for the trend? I would like to know why resonance > Inductive in determining organic cation stability.  Thanks

Comment: @234ff, [have a look at this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/131103/63955). It has a basic explanation of the trend. If you find it useful, don't forget to vote it

Comment: @234ff, or if you need a very detailed insight, you can [look up this chapter](http://ncert.nic.in/textbook/textbook.htm?kech2=5-7).

Answer (score 3):

Despite the strong $\sigma$-electron withdrawing effect of fluorine, $\ce{CF3+}$ has been stabilized relative to that of $\ce{CH3+}$. For example, the reaction:
$$\ce{CH3+ + CHF3 -> CF3+ + CH4}$$ is exothermic by $\pu{13.2 kcal mol-1}$ (Ref.1). It was also found that hydrogen abstraction in following reaction is even more exothermic than previous one:
$$\ce{CH3+ + CH2F2 -> CHF2+ + CH4} \qquad \Delta H = \pu{-28.3 kcal mol-1}$$

According to authors, the only order which can be constructed that is consistent with all observations gives the relative hydride affinities as $\ce{CH3+ \gt CF3+ \gt CH2F+ \gt CHF2+}$. It is also noteworthy that within the references in Ref.1 has given that $\Delta H_f (\ce{CH3+}) = \pu{276.1 kcal mol-1}$ while that of $\Delta H_f (\ce{CF3+}) = \pu{99.3 kcal mol-1}$.

**References:**

1. R. J. Blint, T. B. McMahon, and J. L. Beauchamp, "Gas-phase ion chemistry of fluoromethanes by ion cyclotron resonance spectroscopy. New techniques for the determination of carbonium ion stabilities," *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1974**, *96(5)*, 1269–1278 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00812a001).